# Docker container returns empty response even if host is already 0.0.0.0

Tags: node.js, docker

I dockerized my application and built an image successfully. However when I tried to make a container out of it, I still can't connect successfully.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 4888


CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Docker ps:

```
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
748f60fd36c4        ahchi-front:v2.0.4          "npm start"              34 minutes ago      Up 34 minutes       0.0.0.0:4888->4888/tcp          ahchi-front-v2.0.4.1
```

I already set the hostname to 0.0.0.0, but no avail.
Docker Logs:

```
[SOCKET] started
[SERVER] Listening on  0.0.0.0:4888
```

Yet my local machine still can't connect to it.

Curl:

```
curl localhost:4888
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Same thing happens when I curled inside the container.

Tried the docker machine, and it also didn't work: (This one is refusing to connect, rather than returning an empty response.

```
curl 192.168.99.100:4888
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.99.100 port 4888: Connection refused
```

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You say the same thing happens inside the container? How'd you test that? Did you exec in?
If it's not working inside the container then it's most likely an application/config error, probably not docker.

Comment: You connected to your application. It just didn't send anything back. This isn't a docker issue and we don't have the nodejs code to debug.

Comment: @byrnedo I did connect on the instance by `docker exec -it <image name> bash` and performed a curl inside it to test if the application is working. The thing is, when I performed `docker logs <image name>` the application logs normally. But if I tried to access it, it returns an empty response.

Comment: @BMitch it's weird that there's nothing returning even if the application runs normally because the logs shows as if it runs normally. Perhaps I missed something on build? What do you think?

Comment: Without a [mcve] I don't think there's any way I can help.

Comment: Why there are 2 spaces after "Listening on"?